# Calling setSupportActionBar in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I call `setSupportActionBar` in a fragment in kotlin language .
 I have a mainActivity with a navigation drawer. When I click on the first item of the navigation drawer it should opens a notesFragment . I want to set a toolBar for the notesFragment. When I tried to use `AppCompatActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar_top)` the app crashes when I click on the first item of the navigation drawer, with the error

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

```
class notesFragment:Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        AppCompatActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar_top)
        AppCompatActivity().getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
        fragments()

        AppCompatActivity().getSupportActionBar()!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment,null)
    }

    fun fragments() {
        var tabLayout=tab
        var viewPager=viewPager
        var adapter=viewPagerAdapterMainActivity(AppCompatActivity().supportFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(firstFragment(),"first")
        adapter.addFragment(secondFragment(),"second")
        adapter.addFragment(thirdFragment(),"third")

        viewPager.adapter=adapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far so we could help you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you're using Kotlin you can try to smart cast the activity to AppCompatActivity and then you can access the support action bar:

```
(activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar
```

Note that this will only work if your host activity extends AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 1):

The [AppCompatActivity documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) states that `getSupportActionBar()` is an instance method. By doing `AppCompatActivity().setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` you are calling the constructor without assigning the reference to a variable and then expecting that instance to call the method, similar to what would be a static method. This is not how it works. By now you should start seeing that by the way you are doing things, you are not referencing your host activity, so attempting to set the toolbar would not work even if the syntax was correct.

As for the fragment, you get the hosting activity instance via its `activity` member. There is no `activity.supportActionBar` because it has been encapsulated for you in `activity.actionBar`.

You can use the autocomplete to find out more about the possible methods that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
if (activity is AppCompatActivity) {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.tbNavHolder)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Also in most recent support library versions, where the activity property is of nullable type, you might use safe call:

```
activity?.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Or double exclamation mark:

```
activity!!.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
```

Comment: It gives me error "Unresolved reference setSupportActionBar"

Comment: @Samer Can you post more details?